# using JavaScript how to disable the Right-click or how to remove the inspect element option in the right-click window when click on the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, right-click, web-inspector

I am trying to disable right-click action on the scroll bar or remove the Inspect element option in the right-click menu window on my page. I am using the below code to fulfill my requirement. but where it is getting an issue that I am not able to find and other solution also not coming into mind. Please find my sample code below. Please Any help appreciated.

[Sample Application](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRTXHW2EX6RW) - Using this link you can check the code.

```html
<html oncontextmenu="return false;">
   <head>
      <style>
      </style>
      <script >
         document.onkeypress = function (event) {
         event = (event || window.event);
         return keyFunction(event);
         }
         document.onmousedown = function (event) {
         event = (event || window.event);
         return keyFunction(event);
         }
         document.onkeydown = function (event) {
         event = (event || window.event);
         return keyFunction(event);
         }
         
         //Disable right click script 
         var message="Sorry, right-click has been disabled"; 
         
         function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}} 
         function clickNS(e) {if 
         (document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) { 
         if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}} 
         if (document.layers) 
         {document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;} 
         else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;} 
         document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
         
         function keyFunction(event){
         //"F12" key
         if (event.keyCode == 123) {
         return false;
         }
         
         if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
         return false;
         }
         //"J" key
         if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 74) {
         return false;
         }
         //"S" key
         if (event.keyCode == 83) {
         return false;
         }
         //"U" key
         if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 85) {
         return false;
         }
         //F5
         if (event.keyCode == 116) {
         return false;
         }
         }
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body >
      <iframe style="width:100%" height="473" src="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#toolbar=0"></iframe>
      <div style="width:96%;height:473px;background-color:transparent;position:absolute;top:0px;max-width: 100%;">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why? Even if you disable the right-click menu, they can still just open Developer Tools and go to the Elements tab.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you have?

Comment: this final will open into the new window. may be developer toll dont come.

Comment: I don't see anything that opens a new window.

Answer (score 0):

The right click default behavior is to fire a `contextmenu` event whose default behavior is to display the context menu.

In order to prevent that default behavior, write this:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e.preventDefault());
```

Note that it won't prevent people from accessing developer tools with <kbd>F12</kbd> and there is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: His code has `document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")` which I think is essentially equivalent.

Comment: Indeed, although it's a weird way of doing it

Comment: His code is full of obsolete styles, like `event | window.event`. That's probably needed for something like IE8 compatibility.

Comment: An event used to be attached to `window`? 

Comment: IE puts the current event in the global variable `event`.

Comment: I'm glad it didn't become the standard!